# Vent exhaust leaking even after tarring the flange of the vent cap on the roof

Tags: leak, roof

Our bathroom exhaust vent was dripping after rain; I saw the tar on the vent cap was all weathered and worn away, so I cleaned it off and put fresh tar there.

It was fine through the rains in the spring but then we had a real hot Texas summer and no rain and last week we had our first heavy rain and the bathroom exhaust fan is dripping again.

I went up on the roof and don't see any holes or cracks.

How can I keep it from leaking?

Pic 1:

[image: vent cap]

Pic 2:

[image: vent cap from above]

Pic 3:

[image: vent cap from the side]

Comment: Is it possible to access the attic and visually inspect to learn where the water enters?

Comment: Well, based on the pics, your louvers are pointing the wrong direction.  They're directing falling rain *into* the vent...

Comment: @Huesmann I thought that too at first but looking more carefully I think the 3rd picture is just tilted funny.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory no, if the louvers were the right direction, we couldn't see inside the vent from above.

Comment: @Huesmann Oh, you mean the slats in the vent openings.  You're right, that's weird.  Why would they make them that way?  Also you might need a gap at the lower end along the bottom of the whole outer shell to let any water that does get in drain out.  Those backwards slats catch the water, it builds up inside because it can't drain out because that gap is covered with tar, and you get a leak.

Comment: I dunno, maybe they're designed for use in a soffit situation, and this is the wrong application?

Comment: @Huesmann Here's [one sold at home depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Air-Vent-50-sq-in-NFA-Aluminum-Slant-Back-Roof-Louver-Static-Vent-in-Gray-Sold-in-Carton-of-6-only-SLAGR/308306119) and the slats are arranged the same way so I guess it's common.  There might be a leak inside the outer box from corrosion or manufacturing defect.  Can't tell just from photos.

Comment: Based on the photos, it looks like there's a metal plate with a round hole, which has some amount of surface between the edge of the hole and the louvered wall.  But it also looks like there's a slight gap between the three louvered walls and the bottom plate.  So any water coming in would theoretically drain out the bottom.  Now the OP's gaps are covered with goop, blocking them.  (I still think the louvers are a terrible design.)

Comment: @Huesmann, 100% correct, wrong cap for this application. Guaranteed to leak because louvres are directing rain directly into the vent...

Comment: @GregHill There is no attic.  :)

Comment: They aren't the wrong vents. They're just installed incorrectly, both with respect to the steel roofing and with the gobs of tar covering the actual drainage path. You can infer how they're supposed to work from the [photo of the underside](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/b0ec270c-73be-4c63-9c65-ea6076703150/svn/gray-air-vent-static-roof-vents-slagr-1d_600.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

A local roofer came by and said the vent caps were installed incorrectly.  He said the bottom plate (the wide one) is supposed to be UNDER the roof, not over it. He recommended replacing the caps altogether and installing them correctly and caulking them, not using tar but using silocone based caulk.  Apparently tar is not appropriate for metal roofs because they expand and contract so much.